# C++ what is the meaning of getting pointer to pointer to address

Tags: c++

I have this legacy code :
2 questions , 
first why do they do this pointer to pointer to reference var :

```
 cData& acData = *(*CacheVectorIter); //WHAT IS IT ?
```

and does this delete the real object or just the pointer to the object ?

```
delete &acData;
```

this is the code ( modified )

```
for (CacheVector::iterator CacheVectorIter = m_Cache.begin();
           CacheVectorIter != m_Cache.end();
           ++CacheVectorIter) {
          if (*CacheVectorIter != NULL) {
             cData& acData = *(*CacheVectorIter); //WHAT IS IT ? 

             for (ObjectTypeMap::iterator ObjectTypeMapIter = acData.Map.begin();
                  ObjectTypeMapIter != acData.Map.end();
                  ++ObjectTypeMapIter) {

                 delete (*ObjectTypeMapIter).second;

             }
              delete &acData; // DOES IT DELETE THE OBJECT OR THE POINTER?
          }
}
```

Comment: It seems that `m_Cache` is declared as a container containing pointers, then the first dereference operator is for the iterator, the second to dereference the actual pointer, and `acData` is a reference to that data. Then using the address-of operator on `acData` will give you a pointer to the object it references which you can then delete.

Comment: They are just creating a reference to the data pointed to by the iterator so they can use dot syntax and not have to use pointer derefencing everywhere `(* CacheVectorIter)->Map.begin();`

Comment: Why?, you are referencing an area on the heap, you can delete it. The syntax is extremely ugly but valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
 cData& acData = *(*CacheVectorIter); //WHAT IS IT ?
```

m_cache is a container storing pointers so the previous line will get the pointer and derefence it to assign it to a reference.

```
cData& acData = data;
```

That line would be completely valid but not this

```
cData& acData = &data;
```

Now maybe the most shocking part

```
delete &acData; // DOES IT DELETE THE OBJECT OR THE POINTER?
```

Even if I don't agree with this kind of syntax, is correct as that reference is against an object in the heap and you can delete it.

Remember references don't call the destructor!

Comment: `Remember references don't call the destructor!` What does this mean? Although unusual `delete &acData` will call the destructor.

Comment: A local reference doesn't hold the data, just a reference to it. A usual way to think about references is a way to abstract pointer syntax. So if you use a reference in a local code, the RAII default mechanism of C++ instances will not be used. The delete &acData; will call the destructor as dereferencing a reference returns a pointer, if that memory is stored on the heap, then it will first call the ~Class() method, and afterwards call free(pointer);

Comment: There's no such thing as "derefencing a reference".  "Abstract pointer syntax" is a poor way to think of references, IMO.  `delete ANYTHING;` calls the destructor because that's what `delete` does. (except for types with no destructor, of course).

Comment: `&acData` results in a pointer at which point references are now irrelevant.

Comment: I agree that to use references as a nice way to hide pointer syntax is wrong, but if he can't understand the code, maybe that "hint" helps him.

Comment: i still dont understand why to do all this , why not just use the iterator pointer as it made in all iterations

Comment: I agree with you, the syntax is horrible and hard to read, but that doesn't mean is wrong (and consider the dangling pointer you may use afterwards if you don't remove that position from you collection).

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop suggests that `cData` is a UDT; it has a member variable called `Map` which could be a `std::map`.

So `m_Cache` is a container. It contains some sort of object (we can't tell from this code), but that object can have `*` applied to yield an object of type `cData`. The contained objects could be of type `cData *`, but it could equally be some smart pointer or other class.

So the line:

```
cData& acData = *(*CacheVectorIter);
```

binds `acData` as a name for an object which is yielded by applying `*` to the object in the container. (It doesn't copy the object out of the container or anything).  Note, the parentheses are redundant.

The line:

```
delete &acData;
```

will free the `cData` object. If the elements of `m_Cache` are actually pointers then this is the same as calling `delete` on one of those pointers.

This code is doubtful because it will leave the container containing a dangling pointer (which runs the risk of causing undefined behaviour); hopefully it's part of a larger code block which also clears out the whole vector.

It'd be interesting if you could post the class definition of whatever `m_Cache` is an object of; and also the class definition of `cData`. That would enable a more precise answer to be given.

Comment: Thanks but still why not just get the Iterator to cData* pacData , why to use reference varibal?

Comment: @user63898 reference are safer and easier to use. However, using a pointer would have the same effect since internally, references are implemented as pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first let's examine `*CacheVectorIter`

The type of `*CacheVectorIter` is `CacheVector` and it's a way to get the current item (nothing new).

Now you have `*(CacheVector)` which is wierd. Basically without the CacheVector object I'll not be able do more than just guessing.

My guess is that `CacheVector` contains the adress of another object. Using `*(CacheVector)` you can access this other object (probably of type cData).

It gives :

```
*(*CacheVectorIter) = *(CurrentCacheVector) = cData
```

Then this object is stored into a reference variable `acData`. In C++ you can think of a reference as a pointer that you don't need to dereference. So deleting acData would really call the destructor of the object.